# Преобразование строки в дату (месяц на русском)

Tags: c#, datetime

Доброго времени суток!

Не удается преобразовать строку типа "12/дек/22" в дату (если месяц на русском).
Пример кода:

```
using System.Globalization;

String enExample = "10/dec/22";
String ruExample = "10/дек/22";

DateTime result;

bool check;
var enCulture = CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture("en-US");

check = DateTime.TryParseExact(enExample, "dd/MMM/yy", enCulture, DateTimeStyles.None, out result);

Console.WriteLine(check);
Console.WriteLine(result.ToString("yy.MM.yyyy"));

var ruCulture = CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture("ru-RU");
check = DateTime.TryParseExact(ruExample, "dd/MMM/yy", ruCulture, DateTimeStyles.None, out result);

Console.WriteLine(check);
Console.WriteLine(result.ToString("yy.MM.yyyy"));
```

Вывод:

```
True
22.12.2022
False
01.01.0001
```

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Должно быть `10/дек./22`, а не `10/дек/22`, чтобы распозналось, после месяца точка ставится (кроме мая) - ГОСТ Р 7.0.12-2011.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 12; i++)
        Console.WriteLine(DateTime.Parse($"01.{i + 1}.2022").ToString(@"dd\/MMM\/yy"));
}
```

Вывод в консоль

```
01/янв./22
01/февр./22
01/мар./22
01/апр./22
01/мая/22
01/июн./22
01/июл./22
01/авг./22
01/сент./22
01/окт./22
01/нояб./22
01/дек./22
```

Обратите внимание, что если месяц используется без дней, то формат вывода месяца меняется - `.ToString("MMM")`

```
янв.
февр.
март
апр.
май
июнь
июль
авг.
сент.
окт.
нояб.
дек.
```

Это может означать, что при парсинге месяца .NET сможет распознать любой из этих двух вариантов написания.

То же самое для `en-US`
(`.ToString(@"dd\/MMM\/yy", CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("en-US")));`)

```
01/Jan/22
01/Feb/22
01/Mar/22
01/Apr/22
01/May/22
01/Jun/22
01/Jul/22
01/Aug/22
01/Sep/22
01/Oct/22
01/Nov/22
01/Dec/22
```

Чтобы распарсить дату формата `10/дек/22`, потребуется сначала ее привести к любому поддерживаемому стандарту.

Comment: То есть можно просто сделать словарь на 12 месяцев?

Comment: @Yotic можно, почему нет

Comment: Большое спасибо!